# strange behavior of PHP error reporting in windows server

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin

I have successfully setup Php,Mysql and phpmyadmin in my windows server,but the problem occurs in error reporting.Here is the two cases of my problem.

**CASE1**

when i enable this line

```
error_reporting 
Production Value: E_ALL & ~E_DEPRECATED & ~E_STRICT
```

get all the errors of my Php script but the Phpmyadmin is crashed.it shows `mbstring extension` missing error.

**CASE2**

when i disable the above line Phpmyadmin works properly but didn't shows any error.

Comment: Did you really uncomment the `Production Value ...` line? The reason I'm asking - in some conditions, although the line should not be uncommented (it's a comment, not a setting), the server will work as if everything was fine.

Comment: yes,i have comment both default and development value it didnt show any error messages so that's why i am turn on the production value.

Comment: What I mean is, you should comment back the `Production Value ...` line, and have an uncommented line like this: `error_reporting = E_ALL & ~E_DEPRECATED & ~E_STRICT`

Comment: Can you run in CLI `php -i | findstr extension_dir` to find out what's the PHP extensions directory, and check if file `php_mbstring.dll` is there in the dir?

Comment: i have checked it.Its ok

Comment: Can you enable the error reporting, restart httpd and run this in CLI: `php -m | findstr mbstring`. Does it output `mbstring` or nothing?

Comment: Output is `mbstring`

Comment: Can you update you original question with the exact output of the error message?

Answer (score 0):

check your php.ini file in the root directory of your php installation. In the extensions part of the configuration you should find:

```
;extension=php_mbstring.dll
```

remove the leading ';'

```
 extension=php_mbstring.dll
```